# pip unable to fetch wheels when inside container

Tags: docker, pip, python-wheel

When I try to build an image which includes installing Python modules via pip, the build container only use source distribution and therefore **always** compiles all modules from source, which is extremely annoying...

How can I get pip inside the container to use wheels just like the host system does?

#### When run from the host system

```sh
# pip3 -V
pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)

# pip3 install numpy
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting numpy
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/numpy/numpy-1.21.2-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
```

#### When run inside `docker run -it python:3.7 /bin/bash`

```sh
# pip3 -V
pip 21.2.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

# pip3 install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.21.2.zip (10.3 MB)
```

#### When I run everything in one command without shell, it works too

```sh
# docker run -it python:3.8 python3 -m pip install -U pip wheel setuptools &&  python3 -m pip install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (21.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.37.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (57.4.0)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting Pillow
  Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/pillow/Pillow-8.3.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl (1.3 MB)
```

#### Things I've tried

- Run as privileged
- use the pip flag `--no-binary=:all:`

#### System information:

- Raspberry Pi 4
- Linux 5.10.17-v7l+ armv7l GNU/Linux
- Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
- ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you're using https://www.piwheels.org/, which only provides wheels for the Raspberry Pi. Open https://www.piwheels.org/simple/numpy/ you can see there are only armv6l and armv7l wheels.

Maybe in the container you forget to modify the index url and set it to https://www.piwheels.org/simple ?

Comment: this particular container runs on Raspberry Pi, so this should probably be fine (The Pi uses arm7l), but I'm gonna set the URLs manually and see if I can get it to run...